# Advantages of Yeoman, Grunt and Bower for a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I am developing Ruby on Rails applications and I read a lot about using Yeoman, Grunt and Bower for a better front-end workflow. Some of the tasks these tools offer are already been done by Rails, like preprocessing stylesheets. Are there still advantages in using these tools, and what do I need to pay attention on when adding them to my Rails workflow?